# The output neuron/tensor values after interpretation of a keras-to-tflite converted model are different and mis-leading compared to the original one

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I have created a CNN model using keras from tensorflow.
The model is not accurate yet but just as a part of POC I wanted to check if the output of the same image given to the keras model and keras-to-tflite converted model are the same or not.

Just to be clear, my main intension here is to make sure the output of the keras model and the converted tflite model is exactly the same.

And by saying "exactly the same" I mean the floating point values of the output neurons/tensors of both models should be the same when the same image is fed as input image. This is what I think should happen IDEALLY.

used this link to create the basic code and will modify later as needed https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification#create_a_dataset

**this is the code for creating a CNN using keras**

```py
'''
link: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification#create_a_dataset

'''

import os
from datetime import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from time import time
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential


def download_training_dataset():
    import pathlib
    dataset_url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz'
    data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
    data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)


def test_image_dataset():
    sunflower_url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/592px-Red_sunflower.jpg'
    sunflower_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('Red_sunflower', origin=sunflower_url)


def create_and_configure_datasets(img_height, img_width, batch_size):
    # It's good practice to use a validation split when developing your model.
    # Let's use 80% of the images for training, and 20% for validation.
    train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
        data_dir,
        validation_split=0.2,
        subset='training',
        seed=123,
        image_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size=batch_size
    )
    val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
        data_dir,
        validation_split=0.2,
        subset='validation',
        seed=123,
        image_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size=batch_size
    )

    # You can find the class names in the class_names attribute on these datasets
    class_names = train_ds.class_names
    print(class_names)

    # # Visualize the data
    # print('train_ds:', train_ds)
    # plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    # for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
    #     for i in range(9):
    #         ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    #         print('img type:', type(images[i]), images[i].shape)
    #         print('pixel[500, 379]', images[i][500][379][0], images[i][500][379][1], images[i][500][379][2])
    #         print('pixel[379, 500]', images[i][379][500][0], images[i][379][500][1], images[i][379][500][2])
    #         print('pixel[-500, -379]', images[i][-500][-379][0], images[i][-500][-379][1], images[i][-500][-379][2])
    #         print('pixel[-379, -500]', images[i][-379][-500][0], images[i][-379][-500][1], images[i][-379][-500][2])
    #         npimg = images[i].numpy().astype("uint8")
    #         print('pixel[500, 379]', npimg[500][379][0], npimg[500][379][1], npimg[500][379][2])
    #         print('pixel[379, 500]', npimg[379][500][0], npimg[379][500][1], npimg[379][500][2])
    #         print('pixel[-500, -379]', npimg[-500][-379][0], npimg[-500][-379][1], npimg[-500][-379][2])
    #         print('pixel[-379, -500]', npimg[-379][-500][0], npimg[-379][-500][1], npimg[-379][-500][2])
    #         plt.imshow(npimg)
    #         plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    #         plt.axis("off")
    # exit()

    ################ Configure the dataset for performance ################
    AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
    train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
    val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
    ################ Standardize the data ################
    normalization_layer = layers.Rescaling(1./255)
    normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
    image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))
    first_image = image_batch[0]
    # Notice the pixel values are now in `[0,1]`.
    print(np.min(first_image), np.max(first_image))

    return train_ds, val_ds, class_names


def create_and_compile_model(img_height, img_width, class_names, use_data_augmentation = False):
    ################ Create the model ################
    num_classes = len(class_names)

    ################ Data augmentation ################
    # data augmentation steps makes sure the data is fed to the model
    # 8 to 10 (by understanding) different angles(with by rotating)
    # and with different levels of zooms
    
    # the complete usability of use_data_augmentation is not done
    # currently no data_augmentation will be done(as in commenting in model creation statement)
    if use_data_augmentation:
        data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
            [
                layers.RandomFlip(
                    'horizontal',
                    input_shape=(img_height,img_width, 3)),
                layers.RandomRotation(0.1),
                layers.RandomZoom(0.1),
            ]
        )

    # # below is the less accurate model architecture(without dropout or data-augmentation)
    # # that leads to overfitting (acc. to example)
    # model = Sequential([
    #     layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
    #     layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    #     layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    #     layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    #     layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    #     layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    #     layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    #     layers.Flatten(),
    #     layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    #     layers.Dense(num_classes)
    # ])


    # specify data augmentation by 
    model = Sequential([
        # data_augmentation, # thinking of skipping data augmentation as the training 
        layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
        layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        layers.Dropout(0.1),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(320, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(num_classes)
    ])

    ################ Compile the model ################
    model.compile(
            optimizer='adam',
            loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
            metrics=['accuracy']
    )

    ################ Model summary ################
    model.summary()
    return model


def train_and_save_model(model, train_ds, val_ds, model_h5_path, epochs=10):

    # # tensor-board requisites
    # log_dir = "./tf-logs/fit/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    # tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)
    # # tensor-board requisites

    # # model saving requisites
    # checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
    # checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
    # # Create a callback that saves the model's weights
    # cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    #     filepath=checkpoint_path,
    #     save_weights_only=True,
    #     verbose=1
    # )
    # # model saving requisites

    history = model.fit(
        train_ds,
        validation_data=val_ds,
        epochs=epochs,
        # callbacks=[
        #     cp_callback,
        #     # tensorboard_callback
        # ]
    )

    print('saving model to', model_h5_path)
    model.save(model_h5_path)
    # TODO save history here too

    return model


def evaluate_model(model, validation_ds):
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./models/dentAndBurr_detector.h5')
    loss, acc = model.evaluate(validation_ds, verbose=2)
    print('Model - accuracy: {:5.2f}% | loss: {:5.2f}%'.format(100 * acc, 100 * loss))


def predict_using_model(model, test_img_path, class_names):
    img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(
            test_img_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width)
    )

    s = time()
    img_array = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
    print(type(img_array), img_array.shape)
    print('for', test_img_path)
    print('pixel[500, 379]', img_array.item(500, 379, 0), img_array.item(500, 379, 1), img_array.item(500, 379, 2))
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0) # Create a batch

    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    print('predictions:', predictions)
    score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
    print('score:', score)

    print(
        'This image most likely belongs to {} with a {:.2f} percent confidence.'
        .format(class_names[np.argmax(score)], 100 * np.max(score))
    )
    print('time taken for prediction:', time() - s, 's')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    read_dataset = True
    create_model = False
    train_model = False
    eval_model = False
    reval_model = False
    read_model = True
    test_model = True


    model = None
    data_dir = 'D:/CRM/TT_Collar_Inspection_Project/scratch_dent_detection_MLAI/' + \
        'datasets_scratch_detection/dataset_20211231/feat_original/ds'

    ################ CREATING DATA-SET ################
    # Define some parameters for the loader
    batch_size = 10
    img_height = 758
    img_width = 1072

    if read_dataset:
        train_ds, val_ds, class_names = create_and_configure_datasets(img_height, img_width, batch_size)
    # class_names = train_ds.class_names

    if create_model:
        model = create_and_compile_model(img_height, img_width, class_names)

    # exit() if input('continue?(y for YES anything else is a NO): ') == 'n' else print()

    ################ Train the model ################

    model_h5_path = 'models/dentAndBurr_detector.h5'

    if train_model:
        # calling the model training method fit
        model = train_and_save_model(model, train_ds, val_ds, model_h5_path, epochs=45)

    if eval_model:
        print('evaluating model to check its metrics while in memory')
        evaluate_model(model, val_ds)

    if read_model:
        # to check if model read after saving has changed or not
        print('revaluating model after reading from file to check its metrics are same as before saving')
        model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_h5_path)
        if reval_model:
            evaluate_model(read_model, val_ds)


    if test_model:
        ################ Predict on new data ################

        # unseen notok
        # test_img_path = 'D:/CRM/TT_Collar_Inspection_Project/scratch_dent_detection_MLAI/datasets_scratch_detection/' + \
        #     'dataset_20211231/feat_original/test_prediction/20211229181715.515.jpg'

        # seen notok
        # test_img_path = 'D:/CRM/TT_Collar_Inspection_Project/scratch_dent_detection_MLAI/datasets_scratch_detection/' + \
        #     'dataset_20211231/feat_original/ds/notok/20211229183415.689.jpg'

        # unseen ok
        # test_img_path = 'D:/CRM/TT_Collar_Inspection_Project/scratch_dent_detection_MLAI/datasets_scratch_detection/dataset_20220108/' + \
        #     '20220103_141858.321589_20220103141858.321/CAM1_20220103141858.321.jpg'

        test_img_path = 'D:/CRM/TT_Collar_Inspection_Project/scratch_dent_detection_MLAI/' + \
            'datasets_scratch_detection/dataset_20211231/feat_original/tf-test/test_1.jpg' # file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

        predict_using_model(model, test_img_path, class_names)
```

**output of the above code when used to predict a specific image using the original keras model**

```sh
predictions: [[0.47940558 0.8012595 ]]
score: tf.Tensor([0.42022398 0.579776  ], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
This image most likely belongs to ok with a 57.98 percent confidence.
time taken for prediction: 1.344334602355957 s
```

**this is the code for converting the above CNN to tflite model**

```py
from sys import argv

import tensorflow as tf


if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len(argv) < 3:
        print(
            'err: path to the model and saving path of converted tf-lite model is required!!\n' +
            'Usage: python tf_to_tflite_model_converter.py <path-to-tf-model> <saving-path-of-tflite-model>'
        )
        exit(0)

    tf_model_read_path = argv[1]
    tflite_model_save_path = argv[2]
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(tf_model_read_path)

    # Convert the model.
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
    tflite_model = converter.convert()

    # Save the model.
    with open(tflite_model_save_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(tflite_model)
```

**code for interpreting the tflite model for a specific image**

```py
import tensorflow as tf
# import tflite_runtime.interpreter as tflite
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import time


def load_labels(filename = None):

    if filename is None:
        return  ['notok', 'ok']

    my_labels = []
    input_file = open(filename, 'r')
    for l in input_file:
        my_labels.append(l.strip())
    return my_labels



# DEF. PARAMETERS
img_row, img_column = 1072, 758
num_channel = 3
num_batch = 1
input_mean = 0.
input_std = 255.
floating_model = False

keras_model_path = "./models/dentAndBurr_detector.h5.tflite"
labels_path = "./models/labels_mobilenet.txt"


interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(keras_model_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# obtaining the input-output shapes and types
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
print(input_details, '\n', output_details)

# file selection window for input selection
# root = tk.Tk()
# root.withdraw()

# file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
file_path = 'D:/CRM/TT_Collar_Inspection_Project/scratch_dent_detection_MLAI/' + \
    'datasets_scratch_detection/dataset_20211231/feat_original/tf-test/test_1.jpg'
# input_img = Image.open(file_path) # input_img = Image.open(file_path)
input_img = cv.imread(file_path)
input_img = cv.cvtColor(input_img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
print(type(input_img), input_img.shape)
print('pixel[500, 379]', input_img.item(500, 379, 0), input_img.item(500, 379, 1), input_img.item(500, 379, 2))

# input_img = input_img.resize((img_row, img_column))
input_img = np.expand_dims(input_img, axis=0)

input_img = (np.float32(input_img) - input_mean) / input_std

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_img)

# running inference
interpreter.invoke()

output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print('for', file_path)
print(output_data)
results = np.squeeze(output_data)
print(results)

top_k = results.argsort()[-5:][::-1]
print(results.argsort())
print(results.argsort()[-5:])
print(top_k)
labels = load_labels() # load_labels(labels_path)
for i in top_k:
    print('{0:08.6f}'.format(float(results[i] / 255.0)) + ":", labels[i])
```

**output of tflite interpretation of the same image**

```sh
for D:/CRM/TT_Collar_Inspection_Project/scratch_dent_detection_MLAI/datasets_scratch_detection/dataset_20211231/feat_original/tf-test/test_1.jpg
[[0.88043416 0.18769042]]
[0.88043416 0.18769042]
[1 0]
[1 0]
[0 1]
0.003453: notok
0.000736: ok
```

for interpreting tflite I referred the code in the below stackoverflow question and also applied the change suggested in accepted answer: [.tflite model (converted from keras .h5 model) always predicts the same class with same probability](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56762749)

As you can see here the the floating point values of the output layer tensors are lot different, and so much so that it is even giving me the wrong answer.

One of my oberservation was that tf.keras.utils.img_to_array reads the image in RGB format so I tried converting the img from BGR to RGB using opencv but that did not work.

I also tried using freeze-graph way to create freeze-graph of keras and then convert it to tflite but could not find the binary of freeze_graph or how to run it using the python file in tensorflow/python/tools folder in venv.
This is the answer that suggests the use of freeze-graph https://stackoverflow.com/a/51881268

Please let me know what should be done here, is there something that I am missing or have not understood things properly.

Tensorflow version: 2.7.0

FYI, I have only scratched the surface of Machine Learning & Deep Learning so do not have all the required knowledge.

Thanks in Advance!!